# 88byte output from AES encryption

Tags: java, c#, aes

Is it ever possible to have `88byte` output from AES encryption algorithm? If so, then how (theoretically) and what will be the input byte size?

Comment: I'm sure you already referenced it but you can read more about the algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). Any particular reason you ask?

Comment: you are wrong. the block size of AES is 128bits not 128bytes.

Comment: @drew_w, don't get confused between bits and bytes.

Comment: You are correct, I misread that. That would be 16 bytes then baseline with no additional payload. I'll leave it to better minds to answer your question more precisely then!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography without involving programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, AES will never output that size. But a cipher is usually amended with a [padding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) to layer on additional features. There are schemes that produce output with the exact same length as the input. An example of that is CTR mode. It is not included in .NET but available as a library.

.NET does not have a single mode of operation built in that does not inflate the input size.

Comment: I asked the question in the basis of C#. And I agree with you. But what will be the answer if I use java? I edited the tag.

Comment: Is it possible to apply CTR mode in java?

Comment: The answer is independent of Java. And yes, the Oracle Java SE implementation [does support CTR mode encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher). However, Java 7 implementations [do not have to support CTR mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#impl).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Under a certain mode of operation that is rarely used in practice, it can happen.  But typically people will not encounter this case, and the ciphertext is a multiple of the block size (16-bytes = 128-bits).

**Long answer:** A block cipher by itself maps a block of fixed size plaintext to a block of the same size ciphertext.  There are various problems with using a block cipher in just this way, so cryptographers have developed [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to use a block cipher safely.  The most common mode seen in practice is CBC mode, but in the future we may see GCM mode more often.

As the modes are defined, they typically require a padding scheme that makes the input a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES) prior to applying them.  The most common padding is PKCS #7 (See RFC2315).  Section 10.3 describes how this padding is done.

In October 2010, NIST approved a different mode of operation that prevents message expansion, thus allowing the output to **not** a multiple of the block size.  This mode of operation is called [ciphertext stealing](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/addendum-to-nist_sp800-38A.pdf).

I am a recovering cryptographer, now a web security guy, and have never seen this used in practice.  So if you got a ciphertext that was 88 bytes, then maybe you found somebody using it, or else maybe you didn't get the full ciphertext.  I'd bet on the latter.

Finally, the input size would be exactly 88 bytes if you are using ciphertext stealing mode of operation.  See the linked standard.

Comment: I really appreciate you answer. New things to learn from your words. Thanks so much. But I have to say none of you guesses are correct. Its about a paper, the author gave 48bytes input to AES and got 88bytes cipher (which is impossible). I was trying to find a way to make it possible, knowing that the paper has nothing special. If you are further interested then check owlstead's answer and comments. :)